# How to match angular route based on custom match rule?

Tags: angular

I have next routes in my

> app.module.ts

```
[
  {
    path: 'Board',
    component: BoardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'User',
    component: UserComponent
  }
];
```

Urls need to be custom, with

```
:
```

separator for some base64 content for example

```
/Board:somebase64content
```

How can I tell angular router to match route only for first path of url, so if I enter

```
/Board:somebase64content
```

to match route

```
/Board
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how URLs work.

To provide data to a URL, you need to use query params (or matrix params), in the following form :

```
https://www.example.com/#/Board?param1=xxx&param2=yyy
```

There is no `:` that can be used.

Stick to it and everything should be good, with no code required to make it work.

Comment: I know it is not. But what if that is project requirement and I can't do much about it? :)

Comment: It is YOUR job to tell people that make requirements that they can't do that.

Comment: What happens when they ask "I want the app to fill a mug with coffee from the printer when I sit down on my chair" ? Are you gonna come here and say "it'sa requirement, I can't do much about it" ?

Comment: Before I make statement they make impossible requirements I want to make sure they are really impossible. That's all.

Comment: @firstChild colons are used after the protocol (http/https) and therefore can't be use eslwhere, the same as the slashes, that have specific meanings. If you wish to add a colon to your URL, it needs to be encoded first (which is not what you want from what I understood). This leaves you with either query params, or matric params, both of wich Angular supports natively.

Comment: Great, that's good info, I will definitely try to change those requirements.